# Can malicious software meant for Windows affect a Mac through Wine?

Tags: security, virus, wine

If I install malicious software (which is meant for Windows) using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) on my Mac, will that malicious application be able to affect my computer at all? (For example, see/do things to files outside of the .wine directory, slow down my computer.)

If a malicious application can do this, is there a way to sandbox Wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WINE to run the software makes it effectively a Mac application, with all the privileges of the user.  The upside of that is that if you are running it in a non-admin account, it shouldn't be able to damage the actual system.

However, if you are linking in DLLs from Windows, and the software takes advantage of flaws in those DLLs, I am not sure what to say about it.

For example, I have used Windows to find out the libraries that an executable depends on, then copied those libraries with the executable into a Wineskin wrapper to make a Mac "port" of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Wine presents the Windows .exe you are trying to run a virtual Windows environment and ports the graphics and HID to the Mac system.

In essence, Wine is a bio-containment glovebox. It is very unlikely, due to the nature of wrapper-based ports which basically sandbox the .exe.

I wouldn't be concerned about malicious software running through Wine unless it exploits DLLs that are loaded onto your computer. And since Wine is an app, it can be terminated fairly easily and does not usually run with superuser privileges (unless otherwise initiated with them).

Comment: And if Wine is using the GUI, it will not launch with superuser privileges (try 'sudo open ~' in Terminal)